# How to merge a single commit from a down-stream branch in Git

Tags: git

I just made a huge commit to a newly created branch (created for this purpose), only to realize that I really want to merge this commit into `master`, rather than into the down-stream `working` branch I had been working on.

My `master` branch looks like this

```
A
```

My `working` branch looks like this

```
A--B--C
```

And I've just created the following new branch

```
A--B--C
       \--D
```

Eventually, I'll still want to merge `B` and `C` into `master`, but for now I just want to merge `D` into master so other folks can work off that.

In other words, what I really want is the following

```
A--D
```

How can I merge `D` into master without merging (or losing) the other commits in my `working` (downstream) branch?

Comment: Look into `git rebase` as it is a key component (option) to solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout your `master`, then simply [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the commit :

```
git cherry-pick D
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want *just* the changes from `D`, take a look at [`git-cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html):

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick D
```

Where `D` references a commit (usually a checksum).

Comment: @gravetii: you can list more than one commit. For example `git cherry-pick D E F`